# How to redirect https to http in mvc 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .htaccess, ssl, asp.net-mvc-5

How to redirect https to http in mvc 5 application

I have domain name like example.com with secure ssl certificate also. Now i created a subdomain like blog.example.com . I don't have ssl certificate for my sub domain.

So my subdomain url is http://blog.example.com

Here i am facing some issues

1. If user tried to access url like this http://www.blog.example.com or https://blog.example.com or https://www.blog.example.com http://www.blog.example.com/abcd

In this case showing error Ip address not found or some other errors.

I need to redirect all these urls into one like... http://blog.example.com only.

I tried some code in my subdomain MVC 5 application web.config file but not working..

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

I am using the following code in my Main domain mvc 5 application. this code is working perfectly secure redirect http to https and non www to www

```
<!-- For force ssl and www -->

  <rewrite>
    <rules>    
      <rule name="http to https" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>

      <rule name="redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}"  pattern="^example\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>     
    </rules>
  </rewrite>  

  <!-- For force ssl and www -->
```

I need change in this above any one of the codes for my subdomain redirect https to http and www to non www

I need redirected url to show one like... http://blog.example.com only.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you simply get a ssl certificate for that subdomain? They are for free these days and it takes maybe 15 minutes to set things up...

Comment: my hosting provider not giving access to add outside ssl certificates. Saying buy Dedicated IP address to add ssl certificate..

Comment: Then it might be time to change the hosting provider...